# Based on the output to get value with regular expression

Tags: regex, robotframework

There's an output like this:

```
RA#show segment-routing traffic-eng on-demand color detail | utility egrep Color -B 10
Sat Dec 25 11:24:22.891 JST

SR-TE On-Demand-Color database
------------------------

On-Demand Color: 20
--
 Performance-measurement:
   Reverse-path Label: Not Configured
   Delay-measurement: Disabled
   Liveness-detection: Enabled 《-------
     Profile: liveness1
     Invalidation Action: down
     Logging:
       Session State Change: Yes
 Per-flow Information:
  Default Forward Class: 0
On-Demand Color: 23
--
 Performance-measurement:
   Reverse-path Label: Not Configured
   Delay-measurement: Disabled
   Liveness-detection: Enabled  《--------
     Profile: liveness1
     Invalidation Action: down
     Logging:
       Session State Change: Yes
 Per-flow Information:
  Default Forward Class: 0
On-Demand Color: 301
```

regex "On-Demand Color:\s(\S+)" can be used to extract color "20,23,301", but as Liveness-detection was not enabled under "On-Demand Color: 301", So I expected only color "20" and "23" can be extacted. Is it possible to achieve this by regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be a bit more flexible and if the value can be present after n number of lines instead of exactly 5, you can make use of a negative lookahead.

This will also prevent overmatching if Liveness-detection: Enabled is not present in the current On-Demand Color: part.

```
On-Demand Color:\s(\S+)(?:\n(?!On-Demand Color:|\s*Liveness-detection:).*)*\n\s*Liveness-detection: Enabled
```

The pattern matches:

- `On-Demand Color:` Match the starting string
- `\s(\S+)` Match a whitespace char and capture 1+ non whitespace chars (or use `(\d+)`for digits) in capture group  1
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\n(?!On-Demand Color:|\s*Liveness-detection:)`
  - `.*` Match the whole line
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `\n\s*Liveness-detection: Enabled` Match a newline, optional whitespace chars and the string that you want to match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TNWmRK/1)

Comment: Thanks a million for your extraordinary input. I try to understand your expression.How about this regex? this also can work, but I'm not sure if it will  bring any risks.
 `On-Demand Color:\s(\S+)(?:\n(?!On-Demand Color:).*)*Liveness-detection: Enabled`

Comment: @kingjin Yes you can also do that, but I have added the second check to prevent backtracking. You can see the number of steps at the right top here https://regex101.com/r/Ghq9hs/1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do this with regex, although beware that a parser would probably be better in this scenario. The idea is to search for the string that you want as long as it has a "Liveness-detection: Enabled" afterwards.

The regex would look like this:

`On-Demand Color:\s(\S+)\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*Liveness-detection: Enabled`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/SElvt2/1

And basically it matches also a few lines after you find the "On-Demand Color:" string. This regex can further be simplified to this:

`On-Demand Color:\s(\S+)(\n.*?)*Liveness-detection: Enabled`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/857JQM/1

So that the "Liveness-detection:" string can be a few lines before of after the expected position.

Comment: Yes, you're awesome.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd method, this might be better.

```
On-Demand Color:\s(\S+)(?:\n.*){5}Liveness-detection: Enabled
```